# Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3 but I have ruby 2.6.3 installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So my gemfile specifies ruby '2.6.3' and I used rbenv to install ruby 2.6.3. However, when I try to run `rake db:create`, it gives me an "Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3" error. I even check my ruby version using `ruby -v` and it even tells me I have 2.6.3. Can someone explain why this is occurring?

Comment: what does your .ruby-version file say?

Comment: What's in your .bashrc or .zshrc? Do you have eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)" in it?

Have you run rbenv rehash yet?

What happens when you run "which ruby"?

Comment: "which ruby" should return "/path/to/home/.rbenv/shims/ruby"

Comment: which ruby returns /home/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby .
I am not sure on how to check my .ruby-version file and the .bashrc and .zshrc files .
I ran rbenv rehash

Comment: Have you by any chance open a new console tab?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes i opened a new console tab after creating the MySQL server

Comment: @robert - RVM is using environmental configuration which is scoped to a single console session - this way you can have multiple version of ruby running in different tabs. Opening new tab however does NOT trigger `rvm` function so ruby version in new tab will be set to your default version (which I assume is 2.7.0). SImply do `cd ,` and that should fix it.

Comment: @BroiSatse he used rbenv, not rvm :)

Comment: @mechnicov - Oh, silly me! Ignore me then please :D

Comment: .ruby-version should be a file in the root directory of whatever project you are working on. rbenv checks for this file to see which version of ruby to load. Try running "rbenv version" and let us know what the output is. Should be something like: 2.7.4 (set by /path/to/directory/.ruby-version)

Comment: also, what's the output of "rbenv versions"?